# Getting nth value of a G-Series (General Fibonnaci Sequence)

Tags: python, algorithm, fibonacci, series

How do we generate the nth term of a Fibonacci sequence which has starting values other than 0 and 1. That is, a user gives in two starting values say, 1 and 4, then the code generates the fibonacci based on user input. For example, 1 and 4 will give 1,4,5,9,13,23...
Coming up with this quite easy with tabulation or recursion but I tried googling for a general formula (to save running time) and I fell on this one:

G(a, b, n) = ( (a(√5 – 1) + 2b) Phin + (a(√5 + 1) – 2b) ( –phi)n ) / (2√5)

Please note in above formula that 'Phin' is Phi to the power n. (Phi**n)

where a and b are starting values, phi, as u guessed is (1+√5)/2 and n the nth value to be gotten.

I tried implementing  the above formula in python, but does not give me expected output, (values are not what am expecting). The site on which I found this formula, found [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibGen.html) has a built-in generator for the sequence, this generator works as expected, but my code does not. Can anyone spot where I went wrong  ?

When I do fibon(1,4,3) it produces 13.260990336999413. But answer should be 9; 1,4,5,9

G(a, b, n) = ( (a(√5 – 1) + 2b) Phin + (a(√5 + 1) – 2b) ( –phi)n ) / (2√5)

```
def fibon(a,b,n):
    phi = (1+sqrt(5))/2
    g = ((a*(sqrt(5) - 1)+2*b)*phi**n +(a*(sqrt(5)+1)-2*b)*(-phi)**n)/2*(sqrt(5))
    return g
```

Comment: What exactly Doesnt work? It gives a wrong output? It gives an error?

Comment: It gives wrong output @JakobSachs

Comment: The website is at http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibGen.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
/2*(sqrt(5))
```

but this divides by two and then multiplies by the square root of five. Put the whole divisor in parentheses.

Also, you need to distinguish Phi (uppercase) from phi (lowercase). Phi = (sqrt(5) + 1)/2, but phi = (sqrt(5) - 1)/2.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but no change, actually values changed, but were still wrong!

Comment: Are they close to integers at least?

Comment: When I do fibon(1,4,3) it produces 13.260990336999413. But answer should be 9;  1,4,5,9

Comment: -phi (the second occurrence) should be (1-sqrt(5))/2.

Comment: Thanks Dude @David Eisenstat That was the problem. Please post it as an answer so I can check it. Thanks alot

Comment: I did. See above.